# Emacs regular expression to remove whitespace only when the whitespace is between < > characters

Tags: regex, emacs, removing-whitespace

I am editing a file in emacs and wish to use the `replace-regexp` command to remove all whitespace in between < > characters. For example suppose I have the following:

```
<please help me> hello everyone <HI!>
```

After applying `replace-regexp` we could get:

```
<please_help_me> hello everyone <HI!>
```

To match the entire string we could do: `<[a-z]^\s[a-z]*>` however, how would I then say that I only want to replace the whitespace character?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex:

```
( )(?=[^<]+>)
```

Replacement string:

```
_
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mT8eX7/2)

Comment: @phils did the op able to modify the above regex for his purpose?

Comment: Emacs regexps do not have zero-width look-ahead/behind assertions (unfortunately).

Comment: While @phils is right, I ain't even mad.  This is indeed a nice regexp, and the demo site looks super useful.  AvinashRaj - 10k points in 5 months is equally impressive.  :)

Comment: @event_jr i don't know about emacs. is that possible to modify my regex? Does looahead in emacs allows quantifiers present inside?

Comment: @event_jr got 100k within 1.5 years.. Is this too impressive?

Comment: Accepted answer, so it obviously did what the asker expected it to. That's all it every really needs to do. However, it acts weirdly on this input: `test A><test B>       test C> < > <  f   >`. A and B are not enclosed in angle brackets but it matches the spaces anyway, and the match doesn't capture trailing spaces.

Comment: This works only on the file which has well formatted text ie. Every opening bracket must have a corresponding closing bracket.

Comment: Does not work in Emacs 26.1 . Answer is "accepted" no clear procedure is provided on how to apply it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method using `elisp` -- this example contemplates combing the entire buffer.  I broke the regexp into three parts just in case the original poster wants to do something different in the future with what is in between the `<` and `>`.  If the original poster is not already aware, Emacs has a nice feature `M-x re-builder` to test out `elisp` pattern maching.

```
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (while (re-search-backward "\\(\<\\)\\([^>]*\\)\\(\>\\)" nil t)
    (when (looking-at "\\(\<\\)\\([^>]*\\)\\(\>\\)")
      (let* (
          (start (match-beginning 0))
          (end (match-end 0)))
        (replace-regexp "\s" "_" nil start end)))))
```

Comment: Example modification: if one wanted to replace all asterisks `*` in the string `<tx|s*o*l*u*t*i*o*n>` so it became `<tx|solution>`, you'd replace `[^>]` with `tx|[^>]` and `"\s" "_"` with `"*" ""`.